# Chrome webview application to load extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview

Is it possible to have a webview application for a web page and load extensions in the application?

I have created a frameless wrapper for one of our web pages, so we can hide the chrome header. I am also using the stylebot extension to alter some elements in the page. It works fine inside chrome, but when I run the application the stylebot extension is not loaded.

Any idea how can I add the extension to the application?
Greatly appreciate your help on this

Thanks, Laszlo﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google chrome extension have to be load in Google Chrome (or Chromium based browsers). The Google chrome extension API is not included in the webview engine.

You can open a frameless window with [create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) method of the Google window  API. You should add an handler to browser action click and create a window of with `"popup"` type and the url you want. It's not exactly what you are looking for but I don't know a better way to do it on Mac. Perhaps some one more familliar with that environement could help you.

An other far more complicated solution is to fork the Crhomium project and do what you want. But it demand a large developpement I think.

Comment: I see... Is there any way (excluding webview) we can detach a web page and run it in a frameless window, and have all the browsers extensions loaded? We are running Macs, and in Chrome for Windows there is a possibility to add a page to taskbar which opens a frameless window. This is not possible in osx. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer with what tools you have to do what you want. I don't know if it's good for you but it's all what I see...

Comment: Thanks Emrys, I will try your first suggestion. To fork the entire Chronium seems a little too much for what I need to achieve.